# how can send a json frame to mysever hear i can reserve a json and i wnd send the data

Tags: android, json, post

I posted the code I used for reading the data from my server but I don't know how to send a json frame to the server.

I want to send the data string.

```
try {
    URL url = new URL(params[0]);
    con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    con.connect();

    InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
    red = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String line = "";
    buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while ((line=red.readLine())!= null){
        buffer.append(line);
}
return buffer.toString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume that you are trying to `post` some `JSON` Object to a `URL`,

While using `HttpURLConnection` for connection you can set to its instance that this is a `POST` header request, if you are indeed posting something on that `URL`.

After that you can use `DataOutputStream` instance to write(`POST`) your `JSON` data something like this.

I have written a snippet which you can check, the code is also available on [Github](https://github.com/pankajnimgade/Tutorial/blob/master/app/src/main/java/network/calls/activities/PostRequestActivity.java)

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            /**
             * Kindly change this url string with your own, where you want to post your json data
             */
            URL url = new URL("");

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            // when you are posting do make sure you assign appropriate header
            // In this case POST.

            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.connect();

            // like this you can create your JOSN object which you want to send
            JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
            jsonObject.addProperty("email", "dddd@gmail.com"); //dummy data
            jsonObject.addProperty("password", "password");// dummy data

            // And this is how you will write to the URL
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(jsonObject.toString());
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            Log.d("TAG", "" + IOUtils.toString(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This code uses apache-common-io, to get the String from the input stream, if you would like you can change that.

Comment: @ullaaskrishnan, it would be great, if you would accept the answer :)